# Access forbidden when making request to PHP script from Android device

Tags: php, mysql, apache

while trying to build my first app which communicates with remote server files i am trying to access a php file (with hardcoded data) on my local server from the android app. the problem is that the php file is returning the xml data and not the json however i have put

header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8')

to make sure to return only json but no use. below is the code of my andoroid app and the php file. can anyone please help ? i have also put log cat which shows a bunch of xml tags only but not the data

activity code snippet

```
        String responseString;
        responseString =    com.rrdtech.example.generic.GenericUtility.getResponse(url_all_products);
        Log.i("inside doinbg=",responseString);
```

getresponse (url) code below

```
public static String getResponse (String url)
{
    HttpEntity entity = null;
    StringBuilder sb = null;
    try
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(url);
        Log.e("log_tag_htppost", httppost.toString());
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream is = entity.getContent();
        Log.e("log_tag", "after input stream");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
        String line="0";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

LOG CAT values are below ... i have print the response stirng with tag doinbg

```
 11-27 14:40:18.058: I/DBtest2mainscreen(7476): clicked on the view all products
 11-27 14:40:18.150: E/log_tag_htppost(7476):                                                                                org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet@428bee98
 11-27 14:40:18.710: E/log_tag(7476): after input stream
11-27 14:40:18.789: I/inside doinbg=(7476): <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    11-27 14:40:18.789: I/inside doinbg=(7476): <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
       11-27 14:40:18.789: I/inside doinbg=(7476):   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
  11-27 14:40:18.789: I/inside doinbg=(7476): <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org         /1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
   11-27 14:40:18.789: I/inside doinbg=(7476): <head>
   11-27 14:40:18.789: I/inside doinbg=(7476): <title>Access forbidden!</title>
  11-27 14:40:18.789: I/inside doinbg=(7476): <link rev="made" href="mailto:you@example.com" />
  11-27 14:40:18.789: I/inside doinbg=(7476): <style type="text/css"><!--/*--><![CDATA[/*><!--*/ 
  11-27 14:40:18.789: I/inside doinbg=(7476):     body { color: #000000; background-color: #FFFFFF; }
  11-27 14:40:18.789: I/inside doinbg=(7476):     a:link { color: #0000CC; }
  11-27 14:40:18.789: I/inside doinbg=(7476):     p, address {margin-left: 3em;}
  11-27 14:40:18.789: I/inside doinbg=(7476):     span {font-size: smaller;}
   11-27 14:40:18.789: I/inside doinbg=(7476): /*]]>*/--></style>
   11-27 14:40:18.789: I/inside doinbg=(7476): </head>
  11-27 14:40:18.789: I/inside doinbg=(7476): <body>
  11-27 14:40:18.789: I/inside doinbg=(7476): <h1>Access forbidden!</h1>
   11-27 14:40:18.789: I/inside doinbg=(7476): <p>
   11-27 14:40:18.789: I/inside doinbg=(7476):   
  11-27 14:40:18.789: I/inside doinbg=(7476):     </p><hr />
  11-27 14:40:18.789: I/inside doinbg=(7476):     <p style="margin-left: 2.6em;       font-size: 1.2em; color: red;">New XAMPP security concept:</p>
  11-27 14:40:18.789: I/inside doinbg=(7476):     <p>Access to the requested object is only available from the local network.</p>
   11-27 14:40:18.789: I/inside doinbg=(7476):     <p>This setting can be configured in the file &quot;httpd-xampp.conf&quot;.</p>
  11-27 14:40:18.789: I/inside doinbg=(7476):     <hr /><p>
    11-27 14:40:18.789: I/inside doinbg=(7476):   
    11-27 14:40:18.789: I/inside doinbg=(7476): </p>
   11-27 14:40:18.789: I/inside doinbg=(7476): <p>
     11-27 14:40:18.789: I/inside doinbg=(7476): If you think this is a server error,  please contact
      11-27 14:40:18.789: I/inside doinbg=(7476): the < a href="mailto:you@example.com">webmaster</a>.
    11-27 14:40:18.789: I/inside doinbg=(7476): </p>
    11-27 14:40:18.789: I/inside doinbg=(7476): <h2>Error 403</h2>
    11-27 14:40:18.789: I/inside doinbg=(7476): <address>
    11-27 14:40:18.789: I/inside doinbg=(7476):   <a href="/">192.168.1.101</a><br />
    11-27 14:40:18.789: I/inside doinbg=(7476):   <span>Apache/2.4.10 (Unix)  OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.5.15 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3</span>
      11-27 14:40:18.789: I/inside doinbg=(7476): </address>
    11-27 14:40:18.789: I/inside doinbg=(7476): </body>
     11-27 14:40:18.789: I/inside doinbg=(7476): </html>
```

Below is the json.php

```
<?php header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');


$response = array();
$response["products"] = array();
 $product = array();
    $product["pid"] = "1";
    $product["name"] = "iphone 4s";
    $product["price"] = "300.00";
    $product["created_at"] = "2012-04-29 02:04:02";
    $product["updated_at"] = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";

array_push($response["products"], $product);
$response["success"] = 1;

echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

new json parser class.....

```
// request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
           // json_string = getJSONString(httpResponse);
           // Log.i("calling method =","getjsonstring");
           // Log.i("json_string=",json_string);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            //is = httpEntity.getContent();
            if (httpEntity != null)
            {
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
                String response1= is.toString();
                Log.i("httpresponse",response1);
            }
        }          

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String

    return jObj;
```

Comment: when i try to print the url in the browser it returns the desired json data.

Comment: if browser shows your data.then problem is with your json parsing..check weather you return json array or json object

Comment: Hello Prince... think you are correct... i just changed the parser class and now i am getting error      E/JSON Parser(18145): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <?xml of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
                                                                                                                                        below is the change i made to activity and class...can you please help getting it work properly... i am just a beginner at java        JSONObject json = (JSONObject)jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

Comment: i have updated the new json parser class in my question...thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error i was facing because of lampp. i tried finding out the solution and found some links/blogs saying to update the httpd-xampp.cnf file to include the string "allow from all" however it helped a lot people but not in case of me. i already own a hosting for my website so i put the php file over there and i was able to get the json object output. Thanks masters for your help !

Answer (score 1):

It's not xml. it's html with error. And it says:

```
Access to the requested object is only available from the local network
```

So you should configure your server properly.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion Mighter... i am on the same network and tried updating the httpd-xampp.conf file as well to accept all connections but it didn't help ...:(

Comment: if i can access the page from browser doesn't it mean that the server is setup properly ?

Comment: @PawanRawat depends on connection type you use for your Android device. Is  it mobile network or the same wifi network you use on your pc?

Comment: my mobile and pc both are connected to same wifi network